# ngx-translate custom loader in angular library is overriden by host app loader

Tags: angular, ngx-translate, angular-i18n

**Context:**

I'm trying to use **ngx-translate** in an angular library, and because I want to the library to use the assets of the library in the dist/ folder by default instead of hosting app assets, so I created a custom loader in the library module.

**The problem:**

When I don't use TranslateModule in the hosting app, the library translations works perfectly.

however when I add TranslateModule in the hosting app, the custom loader of the library becomes overriden by the translation loader in the hosting app.

**please note** that it's not translation is what is overriden, but the loader as a whole. Because even if the key-value is not in the host app translation files, they won't show.

I'm not sure why this happens, I tried to use `TranslateModule.forChild` in the library but it won't allow me to build when I do so..
why does this happen? any suggested solution?

Library module:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    // components here...
  ],
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory
      },
    }),
  ],
  exports: [
    // components here...
    TranslateModule
  ]
})

export class SampleModule { }
export function HttpLoaderFactory(): CustomHttpLoader {
  return new CustomHttpLoader();
}

export class CustomHttpLoader implements TranslateLoader {

  public getTranslation(lang: string): Observable<Object> {

    return new Observable((subscriber) => {

      let translations:any = {
        ar: ar,
        en: en
      }
      subscriber.next(translations[lang]);
    })

  }
}
```

App module in the hosting app:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    SampleModule, <----- library module
    TranslateModule.forRoot({ <------ translate module of the hosting app, when I add this, custom loader in the library doesn't work anymore (it overrides the loader)
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient],
      },
    })
  ],
  providers: [HttpClientModule],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient): TranslateHttpLoader {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
}
```

Comment: Had a similiar issue in the past. I think for the child modules i just loaded the module wihtout for root or for child just so i could get access to the pipes. If i remember correctly

Comment: @HenrikBøgelundLavstsen can you explain more? how did you specify to the module to use custom loader without using forRoot or foorChild config object?

Comment: Didnt need to specify I think when you specify it overwrites the existing. So only imported the module to access the the translate pipe, the services already available via app.